# Comparing 2 Arrays with sum values

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, if-statement, sum

I have an Array filled with sum values of the numbers 1 to 10 and in a for loop i want to check the array for duplicates but these values are e.g. 00034 1 which are 2 numbers so the error message i get is "too many arguments" how can i change it?
Code:

```
        while [ $k -le 10 ]
        do
            #the line below is the problem i is the value of another
            #loop the list is in
            if [ ${sumList[i]} -e ${sumList[k]} ]
            then
                    if [$k != $i]
                    then
                            echo "collision k: $k mit i: $i"
                    fi
            fi
            k=$(($k+1))
    done
```

Comment: `${sumlist[i]}` should be `${sumlist[$i]}`

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What do you mean by "sum values"? Why does the array have entries like `00034 1` if it is supposed to have single values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your variables. And use `=` instead of `-eq` to compare strings rather than numbers.

You also need `$` before the `i` and `k` variables, and you need spaces around `[` and `]` in your second `if`.

```
if [ "${sumList[$i]}" = "${sumList[$k]}" ] && [ $i -ne $k ]
then
    echo "Collision k: $k mit i: $i"
fi
```

Comment: Can you post the actual contents of the array?